# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: xsd, timeout, rdlc, sqlexception

I am getting below Stack Trace when I generate a report. Report has been design with RDLC and it is connect with XSD file. XSD file generate query with SQL Stored Procedure. This report works perfectly but suddenly it get generate the above error. Dot Net Frame work I used here is 2.0 *****************

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +212
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +245
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2843
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.SetMetaData(_SqlMetaDataSet metaData, Boolean moreInfo) +277
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +594
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +127
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +112
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +6340468
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +6341537
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +424
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +28
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +211
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +19
 System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +19
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +221
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +579
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +181
 CSAccCustomerLedgerCurrencyWiseTableAdapters.CUSTOMER_RECEIPTTableAdapter.Fill(CUSTOMER_RECEIPTDataTable dataTable, String STARTCODE, String ENDCODE, Nullable`1 INDATE, Nullable`1 TODATE) +827
Admin_ReportV.LoadCSAccCustomerCurrencyWiseReporting_RECEIPT(DateTime InToday, String StartCode, String EndCode, DateTime asOfDate, DateTime todate) +257
Admin_ReportV.GetReportDatasource(LocalReport InLocalReport, String InReportName, DataSet InDataset, String FilterKey, Dictionary`2 values) +21220
Admin_ReportV.loadCustomerCurrWiseReport(String filename, DataSet ds, Dictionary`2 values, String FilterKey) +405
   Admin_ReportV.generateCustomerCurrWise(String AsOfDate, String fromcuscode, String tocuscode, String todate) +253
Admin_ReportV.btnGenerate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +4150
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is due to large number of data in that specific report in that case just add this line in ReportViewer.aspx.cs page

```
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

but if you are having large amount of data it will take some time but it will work